# Find observations of an ID within a certain timeframe in the future in Tableau

Tags: datetime, tableau-api, lookup, calculated-field

I have a dataset in Tableau that contains sales data listing each sale the company has had in the past year. Each customer has a unique ID, and many customers return. I'm trying to figure out how to create a calculated field in Tableau that gives a True | False answer to whether a given patient ID appears again in the dataset within a given timeframe (say, within six weeks of a given observation).

I've tried running it with LOOKUP, but I haven't been able to specify the increase in time effectively.

Answer (score 1):

This would be how I would approach it. Create two date parameters, start and end.

Then create a filter calc for the date.

```
[date] >= [param_date_start]
and
[date] <= [param_date_end]
```

Place this in the filter shelf set to TRUE.

Then create another parameter for your customer id and you can test for the existence of a customer id as follows.

```
max([customer_id] = [param_customer_id])
```

This will return true if there is at least one record where the customer_id equals the param_customer_id for the chosen dimensions and date range.

You could use this same approach to define a computed set, say the set of all products that  were purchased by the customer in the specified date range, or the set of all patients that received a particular service. Just use this formula on the condition tab when defining the set.

Comment: I revised your answer because the original calculation mixed aggregate and non-aggregate arguments (so wouldn't work as written) although the concept was essentially in the right direction

Comment: This would seem to work if it was one discrete six week period that I'm selecting from, but I'm looking for something more dynamic, where for each case it checks six weeks ahead of that specific observation and sees if there are repeats of the Patient ID, and then for each proceeding observation it does the same. I've done this in R previously and loaded the data as a flat file, but I want to create something that does it automatically for use with a SQL implementation. I'm trying to use SCRIPT_BOOL now.

Comment: This is what I have so far but the output is not what I am trying to put out.

`code SCRIPT_BOOL("
    require('dplyr')
    require('lubridate')
    dates <- as.POSIXct(as.character(.arg2), format = '%m/%d/%y')
    accounts <- .arg1
    for (i in 1:length(accounts)){
    new <- accounts[which(accounts == accounts[i])]
    right <- dates[i] + weeks(6)
    left <- dates[i] + days(3)
    newer <- new[which(between(dates, left, right) == TRUE)]
    accounts[i] <- ifelse(length(newer) > 0, TRUE, FALSE)}
    accounts", 

COUNT([Account Id]), COUNT([Completed Date])) `